# Implementing append in lists displayed in tabular form

Tags: python, list, append

I'm currently teaching myself Python and now I'm in the topic of appending elements in lists. With the knowledge I have, I was able to make a code of being able to display the lists in a tabular format. I wanted to try implementing append onto the lists in its tabular form. This is my current code:

```
date = [['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'],
        ['January', 'February', 'March'],
        [2000, 2010, 2020]]

def display():
    print('{:<13} {:<15} {:<15}'.format('First date', 'Second date', 'Third date'))
    print('-----------------------------------------')
    for i in date:
        first, second, third = i
        print('{:<13} {:<15} {:<15}'.format(first, second, third))

def add():
    list_num = int(input('Enter which list(1, 2, 3): '))
    list_num = list_num - 1
    print(date[list_num])
    if list_num == 2:
        new_var = int(input('Enter new item: '))
    else:
        new_var = str(input('Enter new item: '))
    date[list_num].append(new_var)
    print(date[list_num])
    print('Successfully added!')

display()
add()
display()
```

My problem is that it won't display the lists if I add a new element. I recognize my problem as ValueError since it won't display the updated lists with the appended element to the list since it only expects three elements. I've tried putting it through a loop so I can add at least one element each to all of the lists, but it still returns to the ValueError. I just want to know if there is a way for me to modify my display() function so it could display the lists with the added element making it not fixed and still print the updated lists in tabular form.

Comment: You currently specify some formatting when printing elements. What formatting should apply to new items?

Comment: You hardcoded the fact that lists contain 3 items, that's the thing you have to change. Use `join` on your padded strings.